# Remove app on my home screen

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy Prime 7 or vice versa and I can't remove a app on my home screen when I push the app there's uninstall or remove and there's a trash can but I can't do it

Comment: Good idea to show a screen recording of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you especify what error are you facing while trying to remove the shortcut? With more information, we'll be able to help you to solve this issue.
But you can try some of the steps below:

1 - Drag and move the shortcut to the "trash can" icon in the upper corner of your display.

2 - Long press the shortcut and it may show an popup with a few options like "uninstall and remove", if the remove option is available, the click on it.

3 - Try uninstalling the app which the shortcut belongs, and reinstalling it again, but make sure to disable the "Add Shortcut to home screen" option in the settings.

If those methods didn't work, follow the steps I told you in the first lines and send more information about what issues you're having while removing the shortcut.

Awaiting for your answer...